# compiler error whilst accessing subclass's methods in Scala object

Tags: scala

I have a trait:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def makeLulz: Unit = println("lulwot")
}
```

and I have another trait with a method:

```
trait SomeTraitAlgorithm {
  def on[A >: SomeTrait](b: A): A
}
```

and my object that extends SomeTraitAlgorithm

```
object AwesomeAlgorithm extends SomeTraitAlgorithm {
  override def on[A >: SomeTrait](a: A): A = {
    a.makeLulz // WOOAH, throws a compile error?
    ???
  } 
}
```

**Isn't `A` a subclass of `SomeTrait`? why doesn't the compiler know about `doSomething`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is an Upper-type bound. Upper bounds (`<:`) accept everything that is a subclass of your Type, while Lower-type bounds (`>:`) accept only supertypes. So if you want to access methods from a subclass it needs to be

```
object AwesomeAlgorithm extends SomeTraitAlgorithm {
    override def on[A <: SomeTrait](a: A): A = { 
        a.makeLulz //No compiler error, Yay!
    }
}
```

Check out the pages on [Upper Type Bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) and [Lower Type Bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds).

If you come from the Java world and are familiar with how Generic Wildcards work there, you can think of them as `? extends SomeTrait` for Upper-type and `? super SomeTrait` for Lower Type bounds.

Answer (score 3):

It is `<:` not `>:`

```
object AwesomeAlgorithm extends SomeTraitAlgorithm {
  override def on[A <: SomeTrait](a: A): A = {
    a.makeLulz // WOOAH, throws NO compile error!
    ???
  } 
}
```

Comment: thankyou, you are all making my learning experience so much more enjoyable :)